# log4j2.properties set logger level to many packages

Tags: java, logging, properties, log4j2

AFAIK the logger level for a package/class in log4j2 properties file should be set like below.

```
loggers = abc
logger.abc.name = com.abc.MyClass
logger.abc.level = INFO
```

So if I have 50 classes/packages to specify, does it mean I have to have 50 entries in `loggers` and 50 of entries for each `name` and `level`.

Is not there an alternative way to do it with one line for each logger so it can be done in 50 lines?

Comment: No, you can use something like 
`Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);`
In each class that you want to log

Answer (score 27):

You can specify the logging... for each package. Like this:

```
logger.mongodb.name = org.mongodb.driver
logger.mongodb.level = warn

logger.ehcache.name = org.ehcache.core
logger.ehcache.level = warn
```

Answer (score 2):

In the name you can put a package (or subpackage), you don't need to specify specific class name; unless you want specific configuration for that class obviously.

Also, you can specify default configuration for all classes that do not fall in specific configurations (rootLogger).

Look for "Configuration with Properties" section in  [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

- Configuring different levels of logs in property file **is mostly usefull in case of external librairies** (for instance Hibernate logs could be very verbose)
- For **your application** is easier to define a root level of logging and choose in your code the level of the log message you want like this

Property file

```
rootLogger.level = info
```

Java code

```
final Level DEBUG = Level.forName("debug", 550); // could also be a custom level

final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
logger.log(DEBUG, "a verbose message");
```